# Google Map is not loading in Ember cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, maps

I am trying to integrate Google map API in my Ember CLI application, but I am continuously getting blank page with only Google default header and footer.

I am using Ember cli and I have created custom component for maps.
My code is -

Inside components/google-maps.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var GoogleMapsComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    insertMap: function() {

        var options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.get("latitude"),
                this.get("longitude")),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,


        };
        var ele=document.getElementById('map');
        var map =  new google.maps.Map(ele, options);

    }.on('didInsertElement')
});

export default GoogleMapsComponent;
```

code inside handlebar template is-

```
<div class="map" id="map">
</div>
```

Please suggest what is wrong.?

Comment: Did it work not using Ember-cli?

Comment: Yes i checked it as a simple Javascript+ HTML program and it worked.

Comment: I meant without using the CLI tool.  Try it in Emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: Yes tried it's working

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by using views and by removing some css properties. I had a overflow attribute set as hidden in css. So because of this map wasn't rendering on screen. 
* {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

When I removed these the map rendered correctly.